# Integration of an area in y direction

Tags: integration, area

I've been trying to calculate the centre of mass of a lamina enclosed by the following picture:

[image: Two graphs]

I've integrated with respect to x correctly to find the x centre of mass, but I was wondering if there is a way in which you can do this in respect to y to find the centre of mass in the y direction.

My attempt is the following:

```
The steps are the the following: Rearrange both equations to get to y, 
enter into centre of mass formula, integrate, attempt to sub in values 
(the point at which it goes wrong)
```

[image: Attempt]

At which point I become stuck because the entered values for x make the whole equation imaginary, which is surely wrong.

Comment: (1) Why are you integrating over the interval $0.57\leq y\leq 3.87$ ?

Comment: because they are the intercepts

Comment: They are the **x** values of the intercepts.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Why are you integrating over the interval $0.57≤y≤3.87$ ?   That is *not* the support of the $y$ dimension of the object.

(2) What do you actually think the $f(y)$ and $g(y)$ represent?

---

Think about what the formula *means* instead of trying to apply it blindly.

You are integrating the product of $y$ and the *horizontal* cross-sectional length at $y$ along the y-support and then dividing by the entire mass.

**cf:** Expectation from probability theory; you are in essence looking for the expected value of $y$ using a marginal density function.

---

The upper bound of the cross-section will be on the right half of the blue curve.

The lower bound of the cross-section will be on the left half of the blue curve for $0\leq y\leq 4$, and the green curve for higher values.

**Complication:** There is also the small thumb of this hand shaped object, meaning that for the small interval passed $y>4$ the cross section is actually split into two pieces.   Think carefully about how to measure the length of the cross section over these points.

Comment: Thanks ever so much would this mean the answer would no longer be imagniary